How can I send encrypted word document containing image , implemented in c#
I am having this issue, I am making a demo client-server application that include end-to-end encryption for word document. I can send word document without images properly but I can't with files that contain images. I don't think it is due to encryptor/decryptor because I can still encrypt and decrypt files that don't contain images and it's maybe due to sending and receiving function itself, here my code:
Sending files function:
private void SendFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx"
            };

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        
                byte[] encryptedData = EncryptData(filePath);

                stream.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
                MessageBox.Show("File sent!");
            }
        }`

Receiving files function:
private void ReceiveFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
              byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
              int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
             byte[] encryptedData = new byte[bytesRead];
              Array.Copy(buffer, encryptedData, bytesRead);
         
            byte[] decryptedData = DecryptData(encryptedData);
             
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog
            {
              Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx"
           };
         
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, decryptedData);
               MessageBox.Show("File received and saved!");
           }
        }`

I tried to check all over the encryptor, decryptor. I want to send encrypted word documents that contains images in order to decrypt it. When I tried to send them, and I click receive button, it say "padding is not invalid and cannot be removed".
If you still want encryptor, decryptor, here they are:
       private byte[] EncryptData(string inputFilePath)
       {
           byte[] documentBytes;
           using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inputFilePath, false))
               {
                   wordDoc.Clone(memoryStream);
               }
               documentBytes= memoryStream.ToArray();
           }

           byte[] encryptedData;
           using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
           {
               aes.Key = aesKey;
               aes.GenerateIV();
               using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
               {
                   memoryStream.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                   using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                   {
                       cryptoStream.Write(documentBytes, 0, documentBytes.Length);
                   }
                   encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
                   return encryptedData;
               }
           }
         
       }

        private byte[] DecryptData(byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] decryptedData;
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = aesKey;
                byte[] iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
                Array.Copy(data, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length); 
                aes.IV = iv;

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data, iv.Length, data.Length - iv.Length))
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                using (MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    cryptoStream.CopyTo(decryptedStream);
                    decryptedData = decryptedStream.ToArray();
                    return decryptedData;
                }
            }
         }


There is nothing special with word files containing images. So chances are that they fail due to their larger size.
byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

You do not show the code for communicating, but in most cases you need to read from the stream in a loop, since there is no guarantee that all of the message is available at once, or that the message fits within the receive buffer. I.e. write the read bytes to a memory stream until you have read the entire message.
You should probably also use some form of message framing so you know when to stop reading. Or even better, use some existing library that allow you to send and receive complete messages of arbitrary size, letting someone else deal with all the complicated stuff. Some examples are http, gRPC, or MQTT.
Due to reasons like this it is a very good idea to separate your code into parts that can be tested individually with unit tests. I.e. put your encryption/decryption code into separate classes or methods, and write tests that encrypts/decrypts random chunks of data of various sizes. This greatly simplifies the process of finding errors in your program.
